# How to install libsodium for use in a C project

Tags: c, project, libsodium

i need to install libsodium to use in my C project but i dont have idea to do it.
could someone guide me on this please?

Comment: You may use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) as C++ library manager.  `vcpkg search libsodium` gives result.

Comment: Have you checked the doc? You can download binaries or source and build it. https://doc.libsodium.org/